# how to get LLVM opt to output MIR to be passed to llc?

Tags: llvm, compiler-optimization, llvm-clang, llc

I need to pass an MIR file to LLC so that I can use the -run-pass option, but I can't find anything about outputing as MIR from opt. How can I do that?

Comment: `opt` is a IR-to-IR translator.

Comment: @arrowd what would be the recommended way to get MIR so I can pass it to llc without it being optimized in the process?